# Refresh jQuery data table populated using a repeater

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables, repeater

I have a jQuery data table that is populated using an asp.net repeater. When data changes and I rebind the repeater, table does not get refreshed. I can't use datatable.ajax.reload() but tried refreshing it using a javascript function and calling it when repeater is data bound again. Not working. How do I achieve this?

```
<script>
    function refreshTable() {
        var tblCourses = $('#tblCourses').DataTable();
        ////tblCourses.ajax.reload();
        tblCourses.draw();
        tblCourses.fnPageChange("first", 1);
    }
<script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#tblCourses").DataTable({
            "lengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, -1], [15, 25, 50, "All"]],
            order: [[4, "asc"], [0, "asc"]],
            "columnDefs": [
                { "sortable": false, "searchable": false, "targets": [3] },
                { "visible": false, "searchable": false, "targets": [5]}
            ],
            processing: true,
            "pageLength": 15
        });
    })
</script>
```

code behind:

```
DataTable dtCourses = AUCourseData.GetAUCourses();
rptCourseList.DataSource = dtCourses;
rptCourseList.DataBind();
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "refresh", "refreshTable();", true);
```

I have to mention that that tblCourses.fnPageChange() throws unknown method error, but that's besides the point.

Comment: Are you using an UpdatePanel?

Comment: No. Repeater is not inside an update panel.

Comment: But then a full PostBack is done and there should be no problem in recreating the datatable. The problem then becomes that you create the datatable twice. One when the page is loaded and the second time with `refreshTable();`. You don't need the last one.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how the repeater would update the table.  If it updates the DOM directly then in your `refreshTable()` function you can use `table.rows().invalidate().draw()` to have Datatables update it's data cache with the new data.  Or maybe you need to use `table.clear()` followed by `table.rows.add( <table data> ).draw()`.  Where `<table data>` is the data from the repeater in a format consistent with the current table.

Comment: I tried all suggestions, made sure table is not created twice, but still same issue. The only way I can solve this right now is to add window.location.replace("whatever.aspx") to onclick of the confirmation pop up (when record is added,deleted or updated) to force a page reload. The only problem with this is that I lose my current page index with jQuery data table.